# re-creating an animated graph in javascript with charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to recreate a graph from this site
[Site link](https://gamdom.com/crash)

I'm using charts.js library...

any ideas on how to start?

Comment: Reading the chart.js manual

Answer (score 0):

How about learning the basics and starting with something simple? I find that the best way to start anything I'm unfamiliar/inexperienced with.